# What does inheritance actually do in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm struggling with how I should interpret class inheritance. What does it actually do? As far as I know, it allows your class to:

- Use the inherited class function/methods
- Use the inherited class local variables (self variables)

Does this go both ways? If something is inherited, will it be able to read his inheriter as well?

Please give your answer in as much layman's terms as possible. I'm not an native Englisch speaker and I've never had proper programming education. Give me an explenation, not a definiton :]

Comment: Inheritance is an `is a` relationship. Every `Chicken` is an `Animal` but an `Animal` does not suddenly turn into a `Chicken`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a class called `Animal`. In this class you have a method called `walk`, that prints "Animal is walking"

Now you have 2 other classes:

**1.** Class `Bird` that is inherited from `Animal`. You can now add an additional method to it: `fly`. This will print that a bird can fly.

**2.** Class `Monkey` that is inherited from `Animal` as well.  You can now add an additional method to it: `climb`. This will print that a monkey can climb trees.

Both Monkey and Bird derive from Animal, so they can walk, they have a same functionality/feature. But both have a distinct feature as well: birds can fly and monkeys can climb trees. So it takes sense, right?

The reverse is false, because not every Animal can fly or can climb trees.

**EDIT:** I exaplined it to you in terms of methods. But this can apply to variables as well. The `Animal` class can have a `weight` field. Which is accessible from both inherited classes: `Monkey` and `Bird`.

But `Monkey` can also have a field called `max_power` and `Bird` can have a class variable called `max_fly_altitude`. This fields are unique for these certain types of animal and NOT for the generic `Animal`. Which can also be a crocodile. And a crocodile can't fly to have a `max_fly_altitude` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance does **not** work both ways. Here is what I mean:

If you have a class called `Father` and another class called `Son` which inherits **from** father as `class Son(Father)`, then `Son` can use all the methods from the `Father` class but the `Father` **cannot** use the methods from the `Son` class.

#### Examples

```
class A:
    def get_val(self):
        return 5

class B(A):
    def num(self):
        return 3

>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> a.get_val()
5
>>> b.num()
3
>>> b.get_val()
5
>>> a.num()
Attribute Error: A instance has no attribute 'num'
```

#### Analogy

```
class Musician:
    def get_type(self):
        return 'musician'

class Pianist(Musician):
    def get_prof(self):
        return 'pianist'

>>> m = Musician()
>>> p = Pianist()
>>> m.get_type()
'musician'
>>> p.get_type()
'musician'
>>> p.get_prof()
'pianist'
>>> m.get_prof()
Attribute Error: Musician instance has no attribute 'get_prof'
```

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, Updated with examples.